# Is it grammatically correct to use present tense to refer to something happened in the past?

Tags: tense

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/FWdtXZJGPQk)

> "February 9th, 1964. Beatlemania **hits** primetime in the United States."

[From a post](http://www.edsullivan.com/the-beatles-on-the-ed-sullivan-show-on-february-9-1964/)

> At 8 o’clock on February 9th 1964, 73 million people **gathered** in front their TV sets to see The Beatles’ first live performance on U.S. soil.

Why does the first quotation use "hits" rather than "hit", even though the event happened in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say yourself, the first example is using present tense. Not a very common construct, but perfectly valid - the 'narrator' is basically doing a 'flashback' to the actual events.

Comment: Thank you. Is that some kind of figure of speech, a grammar rule or some other literary technique?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if this technique has a specific name.