# meaning of "as you say yourself"

Tags: meaning

https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248902/115654 says

> **As you say yourself**, the first example is using present tense. Not a very common construct, but perfectly valid - the 'narrator' is basically doing a 'flashback' to the actual events.

"As you say yourself" seems to be a common expression, as [Ngram Viewer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20you%20say%20yourself%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) shows About 9,770 results.

However, [I can't find its definition or meaning](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk00sdSk3lzLivjAmBDvwI01rLG4j4w%3A1590750697139&ei=6e3QXtyECJvR0PEP_cmKuAU&q=define%20%22as%20you%20say%20yourself%22&oq=define%20%22as%20you%20say%20yourself%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1AAWABgwvcMaABwAXgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwicneqR-NjpAhWbKDQIHf2kAlcQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the expression is not defined in dictionaries despite  its common usage.

By saying “as you say (yourself)” you agree with what the person you are referring to is saying.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose Arthur says something and Doug says "as you say (yourself)", which means Doug agrees with Arthur, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s the meaning.

Comment: Doug _quotes_ something that Arthur said previously, using it to express his own point of view.